# Raspberry Pi image with a flash filesystem

Tags: sd-card, filesystem

I search for a RPi-distribution, that uses a flash frienly filesystem (maybe f2fs) as filesystem.
Is there anything like this? I want to use the RPi as home-server, and I don't want to change my SD-Card every year,.....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [Nard SDK](http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/) use f2fs for user data such as /home. However, the OS run completely from RAM and doesn't use the SD-card at all (other than during boot)... So there is no wear what so ever unless your custom application creates it.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=19894) topic on the Raspberry Pi forum says that you have to wait for Raspbian to use kernel 3.6 for it to be F2FS. It does mention that the media OS [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec/download/viewcategory/10-raspberry-pi-builds) is F2FS.